# Window path in a variable from a excel file; how can i directly read it as raw string

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I have a line in code which says:

```
data = '\home\aputest\varun\out\SMOKE\Report\2015-10-27\index.html'
```

The line above cannot be changed, as it is outside of my control.

Now I need to convert this path to replace the Windows directory separator `\` with the Unix separator `/` thus:

```
data1 = '/home/aputest/varun/out/SMOKE/Report/2015-10-27/index.html'
```

doing anything with `data` converts `\a`, `\v` and other such characters to control characters, which I do not want.

Comment: Actually, the variable ´data´ is screwed up directly when you initialize it! Typing `data` in the python shell after assignment yields `'\\home\x07putest\x0barun\\out\\SMOKE\\Report\x815-10-27\\index.html'` You can only manually repair it... Can you request the _line owner_ of `data = '\home\aputest\varun\out\SMOKE\Report\2015-10-27\index.html'` to make it read `data = r'\home\aputest\varun\out\SMOKE\Report\2015-10-27\index.html'`? The r directly before the first quote is crucial!

Comment: actual that person is reading data from a xls using `xlrd` So its directly read in a variable; ecoding didnt help

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequences `\a` and `\v` do not get interpreted when you attempt to convert the `data` variable. They get interpreted when the string is created with the string literal.

In other words, in your above example, the bell character and vertical tab character are present in the string right from the beginning.

It's not possible to convert the characters back into their original escape sequences because some of them may legitimately be part of the file name rather than a misinterpreted path separator.

Without knowing why you don't have access to the code with this badly formed path string literal, it's not really possible to give any further suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky situation. In case you can not hard code the source, you can use a dictionary to handle some of the special character in the script, except for 'x08' which does not get read in the first place. So, you will be missing the '/201' part.

```
data = '\home\aputest\varun\out\SMOKE\Report\2015-10-27\index.html'

escape_dict={'\a':r'/a',
             '\b':r'/b',
             '\c':r'/c',
             '\f':r'/f',
             '\n':r'/n',
             '\r':r'/r',
             '\t':r'/t',
             '\v':r'/v',
             "\\'":r"/'",
             "\\":r"/",
             "\'":"'",
             '\"':'"',
             '\ooo':'ooo',
             '\\"':r'/"'}

def raw(text):
    new_string=''
    for char in text:
        try: 
            new_string += escape_dict[char]
        except KeyError: 
            new_string += char
    return new_string             

data = raw(data)

print(data)
```

yields

```
/home/aputest/varun/out/SMOKE/Report5-10-27/index.html
```

You have to manually use replace for the missing part:

```
data = data.replace('5-','/2015-')
print(data)
```

for

```
/home/aputest/varun/out/SMOKE/Report/2015-10-27/index.html
```

Comment: cant do this `data = data.replace('5-','/2015-')`: 5- is not fixed